# get_full_path in django model method

Tags: python, django

I'm just starting with django (and python too, to be honest)

I am trying to get a model method that would cut the self.slug from current URL and return it to template.

This is the method I tried:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    ...
    def remove_filter(self):
        url = HttpRequest.get_full_path()
        slug = '/' + self.slug
        return url.replace(slug, '')
```

But as you can imagine, it doesn't work.

Template's snippet:

```
{% for object in active_filters %}
    <li><a href="{{ object.remove_filter }}"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a>{{ object }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

My core goal here is to have a front-end icon with a url altered by removing current object's slug.

I have no idea how to do it through views, but I'm open to any suggestions.

```
def category_page(request, url):
    slugs = url.split('/')
    active = Category.objects.filter(slug__in=slugs)
    sorted_slugs = []
    for i in active:
        sorted_slugs.append(i.slug)
    if slugs != sorted_slugs:
        url = '/'.join(sorted_slugs)
        return redirect('http://127.0.0.1:8000/catalog/' + url)
    inactive = Category.objects.exclude(slug__in=slugs)
    return render(request, 'category.html', {'active_filters': active,
                                              'inactive_filters': inactive})
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send a list of all active slugs to the template and then build a custom template filter to construct the modified url.

#### views.py

```
# Send your list of active slugs to the template

return render(request, 'category.html', {
    'active_filters': active,
    'inactive_filters': inactive,
    'slugs': slugs,
})
```

#### tags_and_filters.py

```
import copy

from django import template

register = template.Library()


@register.filter(name='remove_filter')
def remove_filter(category, slugs): 
    copied_slugs = copy.copy(slugs)
    slug = category.slug
    if slug in copied_slugs:
        copied_slugs.remove(slug)
    return '/'.join(copied_slugs)
```

#### your template

```
{% for object in active_filters %}
<li>
  <a href="{{ object|remove_filter:slugs }}"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a>{{ object }}
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks, it pushed me in the right direction, I just had to do a little bit more googlestorm and it works! I learned custom template tags - it's super useful stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Your `remove_filter` method has no access to the current request. `HttpRequest` is the class, not the current request instance.

I suggest that you rewrite `remove_filter` as a [custom tag or filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/). That way your function can  access the category and request instance. You will have to activate the [request template context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django-core-context-processors-request) in your settings as well.